# Prevent form submit with ajax if form fields are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im having some trouble with a simple form. I can't seem to prevent the form from submiting if the fields are empty. Is there an easy way to check if the fields are empty, and then prevent the form submitting?

Here is my html form:

```
<form method="post" name="simpleForm" id="simpleForm" action="handler.php">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Info</legend>
            <p><label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input id="name" name="name" class="text" /></p>
            <p><label for="email">Email</label><br>
            <input id="email" name="email" class="text" /></p>

    <legend>Questions</legend>
            <p><label for="qs_1">Question 1</label><br>
            <input id="qs_1" name="qs_1" class="text" /></p>
            <p><label for="qs_2">Question 2</label><br>
            <input id="qs_2" name="qs_2" class="text" /></p>
            <p><label for="qs_3">Question 3</label><br>
            <input id="qs_3" name="qs_3" class="text" /></p>

</fieldset>             

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="sub_btn" /></p>
</form>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$("form#simpleForm").submit(function() {

        var name     = $('#name').attr('value');
        var email    = $('#email').attr('value');
        var qs_1     = $('#qs_1').attr('value');
        var qs_2     = $('#qs_2').attr('value');
        var qs_3     = $('#qs_3').attr('value');



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "handler.php",
                data: "name="+ name +"& email="+ email +"& qs_1="+ qs_1 +"& qs_2="+ qs_2 +"& qs_3="+ qs_3,
                success: function(){
                    $('form#simpleForm').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

                }
            });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: do not use `$('#name').attr('value')` but use `$('#name').val()`

Comment: Rather than using `.attr('value')`, instead use `.val()`. Better cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to cancel the form submission. If you want to not send an AJAX call, add a condition check. Also, use `.val()` instead of `.attr("value")`.

```
$("form#simpleForm").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var name     = $('#name').val();
    var email    = $('#email').val();
    var qs_1     = $('#qs_1').val();
    var qs_2     = $('#qs_2').val();
    var qs_3     = $('#qs_3').val();

    //This condition will only be true if each value is not an empty string
    if(name && email && qs_1 && qs_2 && qs_3){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handler.php",
            data: "name="+ name +"& email="+ email +"& qs_1="+ qs_1 +"& qs_2="+ qs_2 +"& qs_3="+ qs_3,
            success: function(){
                $('form#simpleForm').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

            }
        });
     }
     return false; //IE
});
```

Comment: preventDefault() doesn't work in IE, for IE, use event.cancelBubble = true;

Comment: `return false;`, which the asker already had, should do the same thing. The question was about how to prevent submission if any/all fields are empty.

Comment: @GregL Preventdefault was an extra. I have suggested 3 changes in my answer.

Comment: @RobW, I must be blind, I thought your answer was wrong initially, but I was obviously mistaken. My apologies, sir.

Comment: Works perfectly! Learned alot from this. Thank you!

Comment: @Ankit - jQuery implements preventDefault() for you in browsers that don't support it natively.

Answer (score 2):

In a general sense if you return false from the submit handler it will prevent the form being submitted in the standard (non-ajax) way, but I see you are already doing this - which you need to if you want to submit it via ajax instead or it will make the ajax call *and* submit normally.

So all you need for your validation is to put an if test that only makes the `$.ajax()` call if validation passes:

```
if (name != "" && etc...) {
   $.ajax({ /* your existing ajax code here */ });
}
```

EDIT: you can also test that there are no blank fields with a single jQuery selector:

```
if ($("#simpleform :text[value='']").length === 0) {
   $.ajax({ /* your existing ajax code here */ });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have an if check before making ajax request:

```
if(name != '' && email != '' ...)
{
//send request is true
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "handler.php",
                data: "name="+ name +"& email="+ email +"& qs_1="+ qs_1 +"& qs_2="+ qs_2 +"& qs_3="+ qs_3,
                success: function(){
                    $('form#simpleForm').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

                }
            });

}

else{
return false;
}
```

Comment: Good try, but note the point made in the other answers - you need to return false whether the if condition passes or not, otherwise the form will do a normal submit, which is likely not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple function to make a form invalid if any of the inputs is empty:

```
     function validateForm(data){
         var is_valid = true;
         $.each(data, function(id, obj) {
             if(obj.value === "") {
                 is_valid = false;
             }
         });   
         return is_valid;         
     }
```

The `data` argument should be a json serialized form.

Usage:

```
    var form_data = $( "#my_form" ).serializeArray();
    var is_valid = validateForm(form_data);

    if(is_valid === true){
        // your ajax code
    }
```