# AJAX unsubmit form

Tags: ajax, forms, submit

I've made an ajax search filter which loads when a certain input has a value (this is the search query box):

```
 $("#filter").keyup(function(event){
var query = document.getElementById('query').value;
if(query!=""){
    $("#filter").submit();
}
else{
}
});

 $("#filter").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#result").html('');
var values = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "filter_content.php",
    type: "get",
    data: values,
    success: function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    },
});
});
```

Is there a way to "unsubmit" the form when there is no value? So the ajax loaded content will disapeare instead of showing the content related to the last value (that wasn't blank)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to the server side script? I would modify the filter_content.php file to return all data if $_GET['query] is empty or filter if not. Naturally you would have to replace `if(query!=""){ ..} else {}` with `$("#filter").submit();`

Comment: It may be a similar question with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914594/prevent-form-submit-with-ajax-if-form-fields-are-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the content disappear why don't you just change $('#result').html() to an empty or a default value. This could be done in the 'else' part of query check. There is nothing called unsubmit form. Hope that makes sense